# RavenDB: static index casting and sorting issue

Tags: ravendb

I have a problem with RavenDB indexing.

Simple query looks like this:

```
        var values =
            myCollection.Query.Where(w =>
                w.MyId == MyId &&
                w.IsReady == false &&
                w.IsDeleted &&
                w.Rate > 0)
```

During execution Raven creates dynamic index:

```
from doc in docs.MyCollection
select new { Rate = doc.Rate, IsReady = doc.IsReady, IsDeleted = doc.IsDeleted, MyId = doc.MyId }
```

with extra options: 
    Field -> Rate;
    Storage -> No;
    Indexing -> Default;
    Sort -> Double;

Field **Rate** has **decimal** type.

**Problem:**

I wanted to add static index, but when I specified index like this:

```
public class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyCollection> {
    public MyIndex () {
        Map = d => d.Select(s => new { Rate = s.Rate, IsReady = s.IsReady, IsDeleted = s.IsDeleted, MyId = s.MyId });
        Sort(x => x.Rate, SortOptions.Double);
    }
}
```

Raven is creating index slightly different:

```
from doc in docs.MyCollection
select new { Rate = (decimal)doc.Rate, IsReady = doc.IsReady, IsDeleted =    doc.IsDeleted, MyId = doc.MyId }
```

with extra options:
    Field -> Rate;
    Storage -> No; 
    Indexing -> Default;
    Sort -> Double;

The only difference is that I have casting in static index, because my field type is **decimal** and I'm using **Double** sort option.

Because of that Raven is not using my static index but instead creates dynamic one every time query is being executed.

I tried to do some casting inside Sort() but then index has not been created at all. One way to overcome this issue is to manually modify static index from management console after it was created, but it's not good solution.

Any ideas how to deal with that?
Thanks.

Edit:
Another example:

Type of field **DateTime** and querying using **DateTime** values as predicates (greater than / less than). Raven in dynamic index creation picks **String** as a SortOption, and when I try to prepare static index I get casting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IDocumentSession.Query(string indexName, [bool isMapReduce])` or the `IDocumentSession.Query<TResult, TIndexCreator>()` overloads to explicitly specify a static index. So in your specific case, either `IDocumentSession.Query<MyCollection, MyIndex>()` or `IDocumentSession.Query("MyIndex")`.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Yes I know I can specify index name directly, but I don't want to do that :) I'm not using Session.Query() directly and it would be easier for me if Raven picks index automatically without specifying name.